# Is there a way in Java to pass multiple parameter pairs to a method?

Tags: java, recordset

Pretty new to Java

I would like to be able to use a method in following sort of way;

```
class PairedData {
    String label;
    Object val:
}


public void myMethod(String tablename, PairedData ... pD) {
    /* 
    insert a record into a table -tablename with the various fields being
    populated according to the information provided by the list of 
    PairedData objects
    */
}

myMethod("firststring",{"field1",Date1},{"field2",12},{"field3","aString"});
```

I realise the syntax is not valid but I hope it gives the gist of what I would like to do.

What I am trying to do is to directly pass the data rather than populate the instances of the class and then pass those. Is that possible or am I just trying to break a whole lot of OOPs rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you're trying to do really isn't possible. It looks to me like it would be much better to pass instances of your class to the method as opposed to doing something convoluted with arrays like that. Another answer suggested using an `Object[]` varargs parameter - that's probably the closest you'll get to achieving something like what you show in your example. Another alternative (and I think a better one) would be

```
public void myMethod(String tablename, String[] labels, Object[] vals) {
```

You could instantiate your class for each `labels[i]` and `vals[i]` (pairing them up) in those arrays. In other words, in your method you could have something like

```
pD = new PairedData[labels.length];

for (i = 0; i < labels.length; i++)
    pD[i] = new PairedData(labels[i], vals[i]);  // assuming you
                                                 // added this
                                                 // constructor
```

The method call example that you included would then be converted to

```
myMethod("firststring", new String[]{"field1", "field2", "field3"}, 
                                             new Object[]{date1, 12, "aString"});
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have previously done something like your suggestion when writing in delphi, the reason I was trying to avoid this approach was that it was extremely easy to get a mismatch between the number of fields and the number of parameters passed, thus I was trying to allow them to be passed in pairs.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using arrays of Object:

```
public void myMethod(String tableName, Object[] ...pairs)
```

and invoke this method in a such style:

```
myMethod("someTable", new Object[] {"field1", date1}, new Object[] {"field2", date2});
```

Comment: Really helpful, works just as I wanted. Not wishing to be greedy but can you think of a way of doing this without the new Object[] before each pair. Thanks Again

Comment: @TonyWolff, Well, you could create additional static method, smth like: `static Object[] o(Object ...xxx) { return xxx; }`, and use it instead of `new Object[] { ... }` in such way: `o("field1", date1), ...`

Answer (score 1):

usually...

you would make a class that has variable in it for all the parameters.
then you would build an instance of that class and populate the values.

then you could use that class instance to pass those around.

if you want a whole bunch... then make a Collection (Map, HashMap, List etc.) and pass that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a good case for a future language extension if you ask me. But by slightly changing the way you call your method we should be able to get close ...

```
myMethod("someTable", 
  new PairedData("field1", date1), 
  new PairedData("field2", date2)
);
```

It’s more type-work, but it is probably the safest as it is typesafe and not error prone to matching pairs.

You would also be required to write your constructor for ‘PairedData(String label, Object val)‘ for which I advise to write multiple overloaded versions one for each type of `val` you plan to store.